# How do you set the display value of any DOM element?

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Sometimes I want to update the value of a random DOMNode but I don't really know what type of element it is for sure. I am assuming I will need some block of code that checks to see what type of node it is.

```
if(el.tagName == 'input' ) el.value = "foo";
if(el.tagName == 'div') el.innerHTML = "foo";
```

Or even if certain properties exist:

```
var value = "foo";

if(el.value != "undefined" && el.value != value) {
    el.value = value;
}

if(el.innerHTML != "undefined" && el.innerHTML != value) {
    el.innerHTML = value;
}
```

The el[.nodeType](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.nodeType) does list several basic types, but they are just basic node types.

What is the best way to update any type of elements display?

**Update**: @dfsq had a good idea.

```
el["value" in el ? "value" : "innerHTML"] = value;
```

However, it doesn't seem to work with just any element:

```
["value" in document.createElement('li')] // true
```

**Update 2** strict type checking might be a solution:

```
document.createElement('input').value
""
document.createElement('li').value
0
document.createElement('div').value
undefined
document.createElement('textarea').value
""
```

*Note: No jQuery solutions unless you want to point out [how jQuery does it](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/tree/master/src)*

Comment: AFAIK there isn't a shorter way than yours.

Comment: Just create a global function `setElementValue(I_domElement, I_value)` so you just have to call it when required. Or you can also add it to each DOMElement type prototype so you can do `el.setValue()`. Also, don't forget about `innerText`.

Comment: the second block will not work as input/select/textarea have a `innerHTML` property, and you are not doing a typeof call so you would actually be testing the property's value is not the string "undefined" instead of testing existance

Comment: I think this might work `el["value" in el ? "value" : "innerHTML"] = value;`. Only form elements have `value`. However they also have `innerHTML`. That's why this method checks `value` first.

Comment: @dfsq, unless its a comment then it needs to be `data`, but that is not a display element so.....

Comment: @dfsq, that was a good try. Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.nodeValue

Answer (score 0):

Seems type checking on the `el.value` is the way to go:

```
var els = ['p', 'div', 'li', 'a', 'input', 'textarea'];
for (var i in els) { 
    var el = document.createElement(els[i]); el.value = 'foo'; console.log(el.value);
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xeoncross/95WPc/)

```
el[typeof el.value === "string" ? "value" : "innerHTML"] = value;
```